# Python 3 email extracting search engine

Tags: python, regex, list, email, search

Q. Write a search engine that will take a file (like an html source page) and extract all of the email addresses. It will then print them out in an ordered list. The file may contain a lot of messy text (i.e. `asda@home` is not valid.. and there can be a lot of @'s in the file in roles other than emails!)

For testing purposes, this is the text file I have been using:

```
askdalsd
asd
sad
asd
asd
asd
ad
asd
asda
da
moi1990@gmail.com
masda@sadas
223@home.ca
125512@12451.cpm
domain@name.com
asda
sda
as
da
ketchup@ketchup@#%@#.com
onez!es@gomail.com
asdasda@@@@@email.com
asda@asdasdaad.ca
moee@gmail.com
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
import os
import re
import sys

def grab_email(file):
    email_pattern = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b',re.IGNORECASE)
    found = set()
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        for line in open(file, 'r'):
            found.update(email_pattern.findall(line))
        for email_address in found:
            print (email_address)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        grab_email(sys.argv[1])


grab_email('email_addresses.txt')
```

Now the problem I am having is that after a certain point, the program crashes. This is the output:

```
125512@12451.cpm
es@gomail.com
asda@asdasdaad.ca
223@home.ca
moee@gmail.com
moi1990@gmail.com
domain@name.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Sheridan/Part Time/TELE26529 Linux Architecture w. Network Scripting/Python Assignment 3.5/question1.py", line 17, in <module>
    grab_email('email_addresses.txt')
  File "D:/Sheridan/Part Time/TELE26529 Linux Architecture w. Network Scripting/Python Assignment 3.5/question1.py", line 14, in grab_email
    grab_email(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix this? How can I more effectively handle these exceptions?

Comment: What are you passing on the command line?

Comment: @squiguy I am not. I am running it directly from the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        grab_email(sys.argv[1])
```

Your program is crashing because it is processing this inside of the `grab_email` function. Since you are running from the interpreter, the `if` statement will of course evaluate to `True`. Then, since you have passed no command line arguments, you are attempting a non-existing list element, causing the error you get.

To fix, just dedent! It should look like:

```
import os
import re
import sys

def grab_email(file):
    email_pattern = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b',re.IGNORECASE)
    found = set()
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        for line in open(file, 'r'):
            found.update(email_pattern.findall(line))
        for email_address in found:
            print (email_address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grab_email(sys.argv[1])
```

This will now run correctly from the command line (assuming you pass the file name correctly from the command line). I have also removed the extraneous function call.

Of course, if you just want this to run in the interpreter, take out the if statement and reinstate the function call I removed. You could also do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        grab_email(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        grab_email('email_addresses.txt')
```

Which isn't great, per se, but handles that particular error (while introducing another potential one).

Comment: This helps with removing the traceback error but it still isn't reading the rest of the file as I am sure you are aware of. How do I get it to read the entire file and display all the correct results?

Comment: It is outputting everything that matches your regex. Or it was in the example you provided. You can see the last line of the file in the output, so you know it was read.

Comment: You'll also want to fix your choice of data structures. A set is not ordered, so you'll eventually want a list. I'd sort it, too, depending on how you read that part of the instructions.

Comment: Would it work if I append the output to an empty list that would first be declared in the beginning?