# separating list items python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi please anyone can help me with this list i want to separate the data into three parts, the whole data below is located at a single index of the list, such that each index of the list has a data of this kind.

```
[website='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine' 
page_url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine?answertab=active#tab-top'
data={'email': ['asda@asdasdaad.ca', 'es@gomail.com', 'onez!es@gomail.com', 'moee@gmail.com', 'moi1990@gmail.com', '223@home.ca', 'domain@name.com']}
]
```

such that i'll be able to fetch the datas independently as:

```
website='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine' 
page_url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine?answertab=active#tab-top'
data={'email': ['asda@asdasdaad.ca', 'es@gomail.com', 'onez!es@gomail.com', 'moee@gmail.com', 'moi1990@gmail.com', '223@home.ca', 'domain@name.com']}
```

In my script i've being able to convert the list to string and split it again but i'm not getting the right answer

```
from extract_emails import DefaultFilterAndEmailAndLinkedinFactory as Factory
from extract_emails import DefaultWorker
from extract_emails.browsers.requests_browser import RequestsBrowser as Browser

browser = Browser()
print('Scraping.....')
# url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine'
factory = Factory(website_url=url, browser=browser, depth = 1, max_links_from_page=5)
worker = DefaultWorker(factory)
data = worker.get_data()
# ------------convert the data to a string----------#
part1 = str(data[3])
print(part1)
#-convert string to a list------#
list1 = list(part1.split())
print(list1)
#-------------------------#
value1 = list1[0]
value2 = list1[1]
value3 = list1[2]
print(value1)
print(value2)
print(value3)
```

but after implementing this logic above i'm getting the result as this, which is cutting off the email part which i need:

```
website='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine'
page_url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine?answertab=active#tab-top'
data={'email':
```

Comment: Your original data is not valid, you can't have assignments inside a list.

Comment: is there no separator between the strings and the subsequent keys?

Comment: And you're missing commas between the list elements.

Comment: yeah i'm using a python library called extract_emails to scrape data online so this is what it returns

Comment: i'm not the one who formatted the list likt that

Comment: i'm only fetching data of a particular index of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    splitting based on website, page_url,data.
    
    from extract_emails import DefaultFilterAndEmailAndLinkedinFactory as Factory
    from extract_emails import DefaultWorker
    from extract_emails.browsers.requests_browser import RequestsBrowser as Browser
    
    browser = Browser()
    print('Scraping.....')
    # url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine'
    factory = Factory(website_url=url, browser=browser, depth = 1, max_links_from_page=5)
    worker = DefaultWorker(factory)
    data = worker.get_data()
    # ------------convert the data to a string----------#
    part1 = str(data[3])
    #list
    strs_list=[]
    web=part1.split("page_url")[0]
    strs_list.append(web)
    part1=part1.replace(web,"")
    page_url=part1.split("data")[0]
    strs_list.append(page_url)
    part1=part1.replace(page_url,"")
    strs_list.append(part1)
    for i in strs_list:
        print(i)

***Output:***
Scraping.....
website='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine' 
page_url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine?answertab=active#tab-top' 
data={'email': ['223@home.ca', 'domain@name.com', 'moee@gmail.com', 'moi1990@gmail.com', 'onez!es@gomail.com', 'asda@asdasdaad.ca', 'es@gomail.com']}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Start with `splitlines()` to split the original data into lines. Then split each line at the `=` delimiters.

Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the strings and dictionaries into Python objects.

```
import ast

lines = part1.splitlines()
website = ast.literal_eval(lines[0].split('=', 1)[1])
page_url = ast.literal_eval(lines[1].split('=', 1)[1])
data = ast.literal_eval(lines[2].split('=', 1)[1])
```

Comment: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084356/python-3-email-extracting-search-engine' page_url
                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

This is the error i'm getting @Barmar

Comment: I updated the answer. It needs to only split after the first `=`, not the other `=` in the values.